# VBA .getElementsByTagName() not returning elements

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to read the betting data for the EPL on [betfair](https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/football/competition/10932509). When I run the following sub, elements.Length returns 0.

```
Sub PullBetfair()

    ' SOCCER
    Const soccerEPL  As String = "https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/football/competition/10932509"   ' EPL

    ' DECLARE INTERNET EXPLORER
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = False

    ' NAVIGATE TO URL
    ie.navigate soccerEPL

    ' LOOP UNTIL NAVIGATION COMPLETE
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    ' COLLECT HTML DOCUMENT
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = ie.document

    ' CREATE COLLECTION OF ELEMENTS
    Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection

    Set elements = html.getElementsByTagName("section")
    Debug.Print elements.Length

    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have successfully collected data from other sites such as [ladbrokes](https://www.ladbrokes.com.au/sports/soccer/69222767-football-england-premier-league/) using this method however not with this site.

I saw something on another site that mentioned something about frames. HTML is new to me so I couldn't quite make sense of what it was saying.

I have also tried collecting the elements by using .getElementsByClassName with no success.

An ideal answer would explain the hierarchy perhaps so I can understand how to get down into the table rows that I am trying to read.

Many thanks

Comment: HTML is new to you!?, yet you jump into scraping beting websites. What value does all this effort give you?

Comment: It's because readyState turns Complete (4), while website is still loading. quick fix: Put a delay/sleep in there as well. Some websites will alter between readyState: complete and busy while loading. You learn these thing, when you become more experienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses a proper wait and a timed loop testing for the length.

```
Option Explicit  
Public Sub TestForTags()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, sections As Object, t As Date
     Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/football/competition/10932509"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
         t = Timer
        Do
            Set sections = ie.document.querySelectorAll("section")
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While sections.Length = 0

        Debug.Print sections.Length
        Stop '<== Delete me later
        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

`sections` is a nodeList so a `For i = 0 To sections.Length -1` is used and nodes are accessed by `.item(i).innerText`. You can swop and use `Set sections = .document.getElementsByTagName("section")` and then `For Each" over that.

Comment: Great, nice way to wait!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but I wreaked around based on your code. This is my small adjustment and it seems to work, but not as expected as the code would crashes if IE is not ready. It would be great if you could incorporate others' answers regarding testing whether IE is ready.

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    mHour = Hour(Now())
    mMinute = Minute(Now())
    mSec = Second(Now()) + 1 'Wait one more second
    waitTime = TimeSerial(mHour, mMinute, mSec)
    Application.Wait waitTime
Wend    

...

Set elements = html.getElementsByTagName("tr")

    For i = 1 To elements.Length - 1 '
        Debug.Print elements(i).textContent
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function that I use to load pages. Sometimes I've found the page doesn't refresh properly, gets stuck & never actually completes the loading of the page.

It sleeps for 100ms then checks if the page has loaded, if it doesn't finish refreshing/loading after 3 seconds it refreshes and tries again.

You would use it like this

```
ie.navigate "google.com"
waitforietoload ie
```

This needs to be at the top of the module

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

Option Compare Text
```

Then this anywhere in the module

```
Function waitForIEToLoad(ie As InternetExplorer)

Dim times, times2 As Integer

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy
    DoEvents
    Sleep 100
    times = times + 1
    If times = 30 Then
        ie.Refresh
        times2 = times2 + 1
        If times2 = 3 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop

End Function
```